# How to release an object and clear memory in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, memory, release

thats the first time i post plus im an amateur programmer, so let me know if you need any additional information. i have the following problem:

with excel VBA i connect to another programm (namely Aspen EDR). For that purpose I have an according Add-In installed. to access Aspen EDR i need to add an object. after im done i want to release the object to save some memory. first thing i tried is this:

```
Dim ObjEDR      As BJACApp
Dim Path        As String

Path = 'assume this is the correct path to the file i want to open
Set ObjEDR = New BJACApp ' Create the BJAC object

If Not ObjEDR.FileOpen(Path) Then
    MsgBox "Can't open file!"
End If

'...

Set ObjEDR = Nothing
```

My Problem is: after i set the object nothing, excel does not release the memory (as i can see in my task manager). of course after a few hundred iterations (i have to open a lot of these files) i get an error message, that excel is out of memory.
i read a few threads and apparently nothing only deletes some kind of reference to the object but not the object itself, so i tried adding fileclose

```
'...

ObjEDR.FileClose
Set ObjEDR = Nothing
```

when executing the FileClose i can see that a little memory is released (0,5 of 3MB) but still there is a lot of memory accumulating.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are you closing all the files you've opened?  There's maybe too little context here to make a real suggestion what the issue might be.

Comment: well, the code i provided above is more or less all i do with this programm.
Aspen EDR is not visibly open. nothing pops up in the task manager when i execute the code. just Excels memory goes up as soon as
`If Not ObjEDR.FileOpen(Path) Then`
is executed
thats all i can say from my expertise. anything else i can add to make it clearer?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `New` keyword, there is no need in it.

```
Dim ObjEDR      As BJACApp
Dim Path        As String

Path = 'assume this is the correct path to the file i want to open
Set ObjEDR = BJACApp ' Create the BJAC object

If Not ObjEDR.FileOpen(Path) Then
    MsgBox "Can't open file!"
End If

'...

ObjEDR.FileClose
Set ObjEDR = Nothing
```

Comment: thanks for the fast help :) i tried that before. the code results in:"run-time error '91': Object varible or with block not set"

Comment: fixed it, just remove the `New` keyword

Comment: that leads to: _"runtime error'424': Object required"_ when executing 
`Set ObjEDR = BJACApp`

Comment: Wow man, thanks!!! use to define (example with Excel app from Word)     `Dim oExcel As Excel.Application`