# How to release an Aspen object and clear memory

Tags: excel, vba, object, memory, aspen

This is my first time using such forum.
I have exactly the same question as here:
[How to release an object and clear memory in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655418/how-to-release-an-object-and-clear-memory-in-vba)

In this thread, the question was unfortunately not solved...

With Excel VBA I connect to another program (namely Aspen EDR). For that purpose I have an according Add-In installed. To access Aspen EDR I need to add an object. After I'm done I want to release the object to save some memory. First thing I tried is this:

```
Dim ObjEDR      As BJACApp
Dim Path        As String

Path = 'assume this is the correct path to the file i want to open
Set ObjEDR = New BJACApp ' Create the BJAC object

If Not ObjEDR.FileOpen(Path) Then
    MsgBox "Can't open file!"
End If

'...

Set ObjEDR = Nothing
```

After I set the object nothing, Excel does not release the memory (as I can see in my task manager). Of course after a few hundred iterations (I have to open a lot of these files) I get an error message, that Excel is out of memory. I read a few threads and apparently nothing only deletes some kind of reference to the object but not the object itself, so I tried adding fileclose

'...

```
ObjEDR.FileClose
Set ObjEDR = Nothing
```

When executing the FileClose I can see that a little memory is released (0.5 of 3MB) but still there is a lot of memory accumulating.

Also when not using the "Now" it is not working and I get "runtime error'424': Object required" when executing Set ObjEDR = BJACApp

I also read about "pointers" that might cause the staying memory increase, but how can I find and clear/delete them?
Does anyone has an idea?
I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If `.Quit` *(or the object's equivalent)* and setting the object to `Nothing` is not working for you, then you *could try* relying on VBA's garbage collector to do the job.

Essentially what this means is that you would need to split the sub in two, have the main sub, and within that sub call the sub that will open and close your object. Hopefully, upon the second sub exiting, VBA will clean up those objects.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim filePath As String

    For Each [..] In [..]   ' Or use a Do...Loop

        filePath = 'assume this is the correct path to the file i want to open

        openObj filePath    'call the sub below

    Next [..]

End Sub

Sub openObj(ByVal Path As String)

    Dim ObjEDR      As BJACApp

    Set ObjEDR = New BJACApp ' Create the BJAC object

    If Not ObjEDR.FileOpen(Path) Then
        MsgBox "Can't open file!"
    End If

    [...]   'your code to perform the needed actions with your obj

    ObjEDR.FileClose
    Set ObjEDR = Nothing

End Sub
```

I don't know anything about this object, but you should also try `.Quit` and `.Close`

---

Another method is to **not create a new object for each path**. Place the `Set ObjEDR` on the **outside** of your loop, and utilize the same object every time you open the new file.

Comment: Thanks a lot @K.DAVIS for your fast reply of ideas. 
I tried both of them. 

The splitting of subs into 2 did not released memory when exiting the second sub.

To place the ´Set ObjEDR´ outside of the loop helped a bit in summary (inside loop = 36MB memory increase, outside loop = 66MB memory increase).
However, the memory was not released.

´.Quit´or ´.Close´is unfortunately not available for the object.
The code I posted is in a function, does this makes any difference?
Also the line ´Set ObjEDR = New BJACApp´ adds far less memory than ´If Not ObjEDR.FileOpen(Path) Then´...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to those who are interested: 
The support of Aspen Tech told me that

> ObjEDR.dispose()

should work, but just for versions above V8.4. 
So this did not solved my problem and I built a workaround using MATLAB which opens and closes Excel after each run. So I loose time opening and closing the Excel file, but the memory of excel is not increasing until it stops working.